# Minimum number of bits required to represent x in two's complement

Tags: c, binary, bit, twos-complement

I was reading a book which has an exercise as:

```
/* howManyBits - return the minimum number of bits required to represent x in
 *             two's complement
 *  Examples: howManyBits(12) = 5
 *            howManyBits(0)  = 1
 *            howManyBits(-1) = 1
 *            howManyBits(0x80000000) = 32
 *  Legal ops: ! ~ & ^ | + << >>
 *  Max ops: 90
 *  Rating: 4
 */

int howManyBits(int x) {
    return 0;
}
```

I don't even understand the question itself, how come 12 needs 5 bits, isn't that 1100, which is 4 bits? And how come -1 only need 1 bit? isn't that 1...1 is -1 in two's complement, so 32 bits are required?

Comment: You need a sign bit, so therefore 12 isn't `1100` but `01100` (otherwise it would be a negative number). And if you have only one bit, then that **is** the sign bit, and the range would be from -1 to 0.

Comment: It's basically telling you that positive number must start with a zero, so `-1` should be represented as `1`, and `1` should be represented as `01` in binary.

Answer (score 1):

> How come `12` needs 5 bits, isn't that `1100`, which is 4 bits?

With two's complement, 1 bit more is required to classify the signedness of the value. This is (usually) the left-most bit of the bit pattern, also called "*most significant bit*" (MSB). If this signed bit is `1` the value is negative, if it is `0` the value is positive. So you need 5 bits to represent the value `12` = `01100`, not 4.

> And how come `-1` only needs 1 bit?

When you only have 1 bit, this bit is used for the signedness of the value too and can either represent the values `0` or `-1`; `-1` instead of `1` since the signed bit set to `1` means negative value.

Comment: "a positive signed bit (1)" is confusing.  Maybe just, "when sign bit is set (1)".

Comment: @stark Edited. Thank you. I hate confusions.

Answer (score 0):

A bit is used to represent the sign, `0` for positive and `1` for negative.  For example, the minimum number of bits necessary to represent `+12` and `-12` are five:

```
+12 = 0 1100
-12 = 1 0100
```

Answer (score 0):

Both the 12 and the -1 points can be resolved by remembering that this is 2's complement. The question asks for the minimum number of bits needed.

In a 2's complement value, the value is negative if the highest-order bit is a `1`.

A 1-bit 2's complement number can represent 2 values, `-1` and `0`, with the bit patterns `1b` and `0b` respectively.

It's a little more clear if you look at 2-bit values, which can represent:

`-2`: `10b`

`-1`: `11b`

`0`: `00b`

`1`: `01b`

Note that the 1-bit 2's complement value `1b` does not represent `1`. Similarly, `12` requires 5 bits: `01100b`. The value of the 4-bit `1100b` is `-4`.